# How to configure output report for thucydides&jira plugin?

Tags: testing, integration, jira, thucydides

I'm trying to integrate thucydides with jira, using thucydides-jira-plugin 0.9.262.
I want to get list of user stories (we have no epics in jira workflow) from jira to my thucydides report (like [here](http://thucydides-webtests.com/2014/07/10/bdd-requirements-management-with-jbehave-thucydides-and-jira-part-1/) - feature covereing section) but failed. 
I have configurated thucydides.properties with default values

```
jira.url=http://jira.test.ru    
jira.project=test    
jira.username=testuser   
jira.password=testpassword
```

Links form report to jira works fine.

In log I see these:

```
[INFO] Reading requirements from net.thucydides.plugins.jira.requirements.JIRARequirementsProvider@342ee097
[INFO] Loading root requirements: issuetype = epic and project=test
[INFO] Requirements found:[]
[INFO] Generating release reports for: []
```

Is there any way to change issuetype for root requirements?
May be extended manual for integrating thucydides with jira somewhere exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the class `net.thucydides.plugins.jira.requirements.JIRARequirementsProvider`

---

modify the method rootRequirementsJQL()

```
private String rootRequirementsJQL() {

       return "issuetype = epic and project=" + getProjectKey();
    }
```

### There you go!

The relevant Code can be found here [Grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.thucydides.plugins.jira/thucydides-jira-requirements-provider/0.9.220-RC1/net/thucydides/plugins/jira/requirements/JIRARequirementsProvider.java#JIRARequirementsProvider.rootRequirementsJQL%28%29)

A good Doumentation can be found here [wakaleo](http://www.wakaleo.com/thucydides-one-page/thucydides.html)

---

EDIT: You can add any JQL you want here.